# "ECONNREFUSED" error after containering Node.js (Express)

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have node.js playing a role of "reverse proxy" which hides the main server (application).

It worked fine before I containerized but it gets me an error while `npm install` in Docker - `reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`

Seems like ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://1270.0.1:8080" didn't work.

What might cause the problem? + How can I possibly fix this?

Dockerfile in for Node.js - Run command: `docker build -t saml-enabled-reverse-proxy .;docker run -it -p 8446:8446 saml-enabled-reverse-proxy bash`

```
FROM node:12.10.0

ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://127.0.0.1:8080"

# Create app directory

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# RUN npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080
# RUN npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080
RUN npm config set proxy null
RUN npm config set https-proxy null
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8446
CMD [ "node", "src/index.js" ]
```

Application Dockerfile
port 8080 - application (hided by reverse proxy)

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...

ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:8446"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://127.0.0.1:8446"
```

Comment: How did you start the container? Are you exposing the port when running the container? Can you share the command you use to start the container as well.

Comment: Yes! I just updated

Comment: node.js is running in 8446 for reverse proxy and the actual app is running in 8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**
From the container's point of view, `127.0.0.1` is the ip address of itself -- **not the host OS**. That means you shouldn't set `127.0.0.1:8080` as a `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` because your container would be calling itself so it won't reach the Internet. This is why your `npm install` isn't working.

Similarly, your main application behind the node.js proxy should not be using

```
...
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:8446"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://127.0.0.1:8446"
...
```

because that would be calling itself at port `8446` and not the 8446 of the host OS (which you intended to route to the other container running the node.js proxy, but this will never work).

**The Solution**
You have to use something like docker compose or docker swarm to link the two containers' network. Refer to the following example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  proxy:
    image: myproxy
    port:
      - 8080:8080

  app:
    image: myapp
```

Also, remove the following lines from your proxy dockerfile and rebuild the image.

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Similarly, change the main application dockerfile from this

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:8446"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://127.0.0.1:8446"
```

to

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://proxy:8446"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://proxy:8446"
```

Now run `docker-compose up` with this configuration, and your main `app` will be able to reach `proxy` container by the host name `proxy` rather than `127.0.0.1`. Which means that you will use `proxy:8080` to use the proxy running on port 8080.

PS: You are able to route to the docker containers/services via their service name because docker has a service discovery mechanism it maintains internally and it will resolve the ip address of these conatiners dynamically. This is essential to containers because containers can be destroyed and recreated at any time which means that IP addresses can change at any time. In order to resolve this, docker maintains a key-value store which maps service/host names to the IP addresses of these 
containers and resolve them for containers that are trying to reach other containers. Make sure to change all the IP addresses within your app to use host/service names instead of static IP addresses if they should route to other docker containers/services.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app`

Comment: Where does this error `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app` appear?

Comment: In proxy (8446) after running compose-up and opening the page.

Comment: I'm getting `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080` error again oh no; I set `ENV HTTP_PROXY "<proxy>:8446"` in `app` container's Dockerfile.